# Поехали кнопки в очередях проверок

Tags: дефект, дизайн, очередь-проверок

В очередях проверок (как минимум: предлагаемые правки, повторное открытие) поехали кнопки:

> [image: предлагаемые правки]

> [image: повторное открытие]

Оказалось, в некоторых ситуациях англоязычный интерфейс тоже страдает: [Processing a suggested edit in popup wraps buttons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305020/339911)

Comment: Не только там поехало.

Comment: @Suvitruf ага. Видимо другие очереди были пусты на момента постинга багрепорта.

Comment: так а как они должны отображаться ?

Comment: @L11VADIS раньше были в ряд

Comment: так как этот ряд должны себя вести при таком масштабе? гамбургер там должен какой появляться или полоса прокрутки?

Comment: или не устраивает что строка ведет себя по арабски.