# Как поменять вердикт для сообщения низкого качества?

Tags: поддержка, очередь-проверок

Как после проверки сообщения низкого качества сменить вердикт проверенного сообщения? Я хотел нажать **рекомендовать удаление**, но вместо этого нажал другую кнопку, из-за того, что поехали кнопки: в частности, эта проблема с кнопками уже  поднималась в этом [вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6516/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8F%D1%85-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA).

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я знаю, в данном случае выбор уже не изменить самостоятельно. Будь это голосование по вопросу, то голос за закрытие можно было бы отозвать, посетив страницу вопроса. С ответами такого функционала не предусмотрено. Можно поставить тревогу на сообщении с комментарием для модератора, возможно, он что-то сможет сделать (хотя не уверен).

Comment: Неа, только восстановить удалённый. Либо, если проверка не завершена, обработать её и ответ исчезнет из очереди проверок.